# Incorrect mean calculation with.UpdateCursor ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, cursor

I find this code here, but the results of calculation are not correct.
Field list is correct:
`[u'T34TET20160527', u'T34TET20160606', u'T34TET20160616', 'Mean_16']`

I calculated mean with Field calculator in the next column in order to check it, but there are not same.

[image]

Do you know why?

```
TableToCalc ='pont'
field_names=[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(TableToCalc,'*T34TET2016*')] 
field_names.append('Mean_16') #add your mean field to the list

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(TableToCalc,field_names) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         row[-1]=sum(row[:-2])/len(row[:-2]) #Calculate mean and assign this to the mean field (-1)
         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your indexing is incorrect, you are leaving one field out of the calculation:

```
field_names = [u'T34TET20160527', u'T34TET20160606', u'T34TET20160616', 'Mean_16']

print(field_names[:-2])
['T34TET20160527', 'T34TET20160606']

print(field_names[:-1])
['T34TET20160527', 'T34TET20160606', 'T34TET20160616']
```

So
`row[:-2]` should be `row[:-1]`
in `row[-1]=sum(row[:-2])/len(row[:-2])`